# What version of Apache Tika has been used to create the following example Tika code ?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I found the following example source code online, it's called MyFirstTika.java and I cannot figure out which version of Tika has been used to compile it. Or are all version of Tika compatible together ?

[The code is linked here](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/MyFirstTika.java)

Any tip appreciate thanks

Answer (score 1):

The link you've given is, as shown by [the /master/ in the URL](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/MyFirstTika.java), for the very latest version of Apache Tika as stored in Git

If you want to get the Tika examples for a different, specific version, you should get the Tika Examples package that comes with that release. Alternately, you should fetch from the Git tag for that release, eg [from the 1.13 tag for the Tika 1.13 release](https://github.com/apache/tika/releases/tag/1.13)